# Using tableau-api with a gatsbyjs site

Tags: reactjs, tableau-api, gatsby

Does anyone know if you can run this npm package Tableau API with GatstbyJS? I've checked the official plugins via Gatsbyjs official site and there doesn't seem to query anything.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tableau-api
https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this with a Gatsby site, you just have to be cognizant of the [challenges of working with thid-party scripts that manipulate the DOM inside of a React managed node](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html).